# Python: generate a list of unique random numbers having a min and max amount of digits

Tags: python, random

I would like to create a function that returns a list of unique random numbers having a min and max amount of digits.

I could use sample of random to create a list of unique random numbers but I have to pass a range. I would like to modify it to pass a min and max amount of digits.

For example min amount of digits is 1 and max amount of digits is 4

So it should create a random number in the range of (0, 9999)

Or if the min and max are both 1 it should create a list of random unique numbers in the range of (0, 9)

I was trying to do

```
from random import sample

sample(range(x,y), k)
```

But my problem is now how to convert the min and max amount of digits to a range

Comment: Your `x` is 0, `y` is 9999, `k` is number of randoms. Did you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***"But my problem is now how to convert the min and max amount of digits to a range"***

Say `min_dig = 1` and `max_dig = 4`:

```
>>> low = 10**(min_dig - 1) if min_dig>1 else 0
>>> low
0
>>> high = 10**(max_dig) - 1
>>> high
9999
```

Comment: It seems that -1 to high is not needed

Answer (score 2):

Using power of 10, you'll reach this easily

- `10 ** (min_d - 1)` will values 1, 10, 100, ...
- `10 ** max_d` will values 9, 99, 999, ... as the upper bound of range is exclusive

```
min_d = 2
max_d = 5
result = sample(range(10 ** (min_d - 1), 10 ** max_d), 10)

# Use the following if you're unsunre of the bounds
print(10 ** (min_digit - 1)) # 10
print(10 ** max_digit - 1)   # 99999
```

Answer (score 1):

Either convert string to int, or you may use directly orders of digit,

```
>>> foo = lambda x, y: range(int('0'*x), int('9'*y))
>>> sample(foo(1, 4), 3)
[1440, 6542, 1731]
>>> sample(foo(1, 1), 3)
[3, 5, 8]
```

For other way, foo can be like this:

```
foo = lambda x, y: range(10**(x-1) - 1, 10**(y)-1)
```